# Using variables from other functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have searched the internet trying to find a good answer for this question. What I mainly found is suggestions to move the variable in the global scope, or using the functions as parameters for the function I want to use the variable in, but without explanation on how that works

To explain my dilema, lets say we have this piece of code:

```
function foo(){
 var x = 2;
}

function bar(){
 var z = 2;
}

function compare(foo,bar){
 if ( z === x ) {
  console.log("text");
}
}
```

This is the problem I'm facing. Is the code I've written above correct and if I call the compare() function it should console log "text" ?

Comment: `x` & `z` are _local_ to the function and not accessible from outside of function.

Comment: Well haven't you tested your actual code before asking? It won't work.

Comment: I know it wont work. I just gave the code as an example about how I understand  it from what I've found searching for the answer.

Comment: In JavaScript each function has its own scope, so variables local to a function aren't accessible outside this function.

In your case `x` and `y` are respectively local to `foo` and `bar` functions, so they're only accessible inside these functions scopes, and calling them in the `compare` function` will raise an Error because `x` and `y` are not defined in this function.

Answer (score 1):

declare with globel variable it's will easy to pass Another function

```js
var x;
var y;

function foo(){
 x = 2;
}

function bar(){
  z = 2;
}

function compare(){
 if ( z === x ) {
  console.log("text");
}
}

foo()
bar()
compare();
```

Comment: So this is the only options, declaring the variables globally ?

Comment: Its the mostly used one and easy way.Or using with [localstorge](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local) .You wish to save the data to locally and retrieve the data .